# heartbleed affect the 3rd party php server receipt verify of itunes?

Tags: php, ios, in-app-purchase, heartbleed-bug

I have a working 3rd party php codes verify the receipt sent from ipad.
but it seems https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt no long response to my php code.
there's not even an error stat like `{"status":21000}` if I visite the url directly.
I've tried different ways on server side, like curl_exec($ch); or file_get_contents
even the simple test get nothing returned at all.

```
$result = file_get_contents('https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt');
echo $result;
```

**I wonder if this is caused by heartbleed and what can I do?**

my original working php code:

```
if ($isSandbox) {   
        $endpoint = 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';   
    }   
    else {   
        $endpoint = 'https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';   
    }   

// Connect to Apple server and validate.
$postData = json_encode(array("receipt-data" => $receipt));

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $postData
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($endpoint, false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after hours searching and checking, I finally figure this out, here's what happened:

1. I upload the test file to another server, turns out it's working so
   not a php source problem.
2. I added

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', '1');
   ```

   to the php file got the error code is  `file-get-contents Couldn't
   resolve host name`
3. so I remember I yum update all the server software yesterday to
   deal with heartbleed. and seems some update modified the
   resolv.conf.
4. I changed the resolv.conf added google `nameserver
   8.8.8.8` but still not working
5. restart the nginx and php-fpm, problem solved